# Decide if the series converges and prove it using comparison test: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3k^{2}+k+1}{k^{4}+k^{3}+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Decide if the series converges and prove it using comparison test:
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3k^{2}+k+1}{k^{4}+k^{3}+4}$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3k^{2}+k+1}{k^{4}+k^{3}+4}< \frac{k^{2}+k}{k^{4}+k^{3}} < \frac{k^{2}}{k^{4}} \leq \frac{1}{k^{2}}$$

We know (from our readings) that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ is a converging series.

Thus the complete series will converge.

Did I do everything correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following your idea I would write
$$\frac{3k^{2}+k+1}{k^{4}+k^{3}+4}< \frac{3k^{2}+3k}{k^{4}+k^{3}} = \frac{3k}{k^{3}} = \frac{3}{k^{2}}.$$
As regards your inequalities, how do you justify that 
$$\frac{3k^{2}+k+1}{k^{4}+k^{3}+4}< \frac{k^{2}+k}{k^{4}+k^{3}}?$$
Notice that if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive numbers
$$a<c\quad \mbox{and}\quad d<b\Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}.$$

Comment: Thank you! So mine is wrong or correct too?

Comment: I justify because no matter what I put in for $k$, it will be bigger because The one enumerator will always be bigger than the other one, so for the denumerators. Or can $k$ be a real number? It wasn't given in the task however..

Comment: @cnmesr To have a bigger fraction you increase the numerator and/or decrease the denominator.

Comment: Ok I understand now. So in the end you would conclude like that: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{k^{2}}$ will converge because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ converges and thus the complete series will converge as well. ?

Comment: @cnmesr Yep! Since the terms of your series are non-negative you can now apply the Comparison Test.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this could be written more precisely. For example the second inequality does not look right. I would suggest the following.
$$\frac{3k^2+k+1}{k^4+k^3+4}=\frac{k^2}{k^4} \cdot \frac{3+1/k +1/k^2}{1+1/k} \frac{1}{k^2} \cdot \frac{3 + 1+ 1}{1+1}. $$
Now one can conclude that each of the entries of the sum is smaller or equal to $\frac{5}{2k^2}$. Therefore, according to your readings, the sum converges.